# Dedekind Domain gives rise to "smooth" curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I have already seen multiple times (e.g. in Neukirch ANT, Chapter 1.13) that if we have a one-dimensional noetherian ring $R$, then the spectrum Spec$(R)$ defines a smooth (i.e. non-singular) curve if and only if it is dedekind, i.e. integrally closed.

My question is now how to even start to prove this or in other words: What happens at singular points of a curve such that the ring is not integrally closed any more?

P.S. I know that localisation of Dedekind rings are discrete valuation rings (and thus regular local rings of dimension $1$). Can this be somehow used (i.e. is there a theorem stating that if we have vanishing partial derivatives, i.e. a singular point, then the corresponding local ring is not regular of dimension 1)?

Comment: By the definition of regularity and NAK, the localisation of $R$ at a non zero prime ideal is regular iff its maximal ideal is principal. By Atiyah-MacDonald, Prop. 9.2, p. 94, this is equivalent to requiring that this localisation is integrally closed.

Comment: Thanks! How does the notion of regularity of a point $p$ in a variety (i.e. the localisation of $R$ at $p$ is a regular local ring of dimension 1) correspond to the partial derivatives vanishing at $p$? I think this should be connected to the dimension of the Zariski tangent space, however I can't seem to find anything more concrete about this.

Comment: For this, see Th. I.5.1, p. 32 in Hartshorne.